# Question about Chapter 15 Problem 29c i) and ii) of Spivak's Calculus

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, proof-writing

Chapter 15's Problem 29c i) and ii) of Spivak's *Calculus* (4th edition) has me a little flustered.  The context of this problem is important and is offered at the beginning of the problem:

> Yet another development of the trigonometric functions was briefly mentioned in the text - starting with inverse functions defined by integrals. It is convenient to begin with $\arctan$, since this function is defined for all $x$. To do this problem, **pretend that you have never heard of the trigonometric functions**.

I will also list problem 29a and 29b to add further context:

> (a) Let $\alpha(x)=\int^x_0(1+t^2)^{-1}dt$. Prove that $\alpha$ is odd and increase, and that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\alpha(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\alpha(x)$ both exist and are negatives of each other. If we define $\pi=2\lim_{x\to \infty}\alpha(x)$, then $\alpha^{-1}$ is defined on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$

> (b) Show that $(\alpha^{-1})’(x)=1+[\alpha^{-1}(x)]^2$

---

Now, here is the prompt for this post's question of interest, Problem 29c:

> For $-\pi/2 \lt x \lt \pi/2$, define $\tan(x)=\alpha^{-1}(x)$, and then define $\sin(x)=\tan(x)/\sqrt{1+\tan^2(x)}$. Show that (i) $\lim_{x \to \pi/2^-}\sin(x)=1$ and (ii) $\lim_{x \to -\pi/2^+}\sin(x)=-1$.

Here is the **answer key**'s solution, which is the source of my confusion:

> Since (b) shows that $\tan'(x)=1+\tan^2(x)$, l'Hopital's Rule gives \begin{align}\lim_{x \to \pi/2^-}\sin(x)&=\lim_{x \to \pi/2^-}\frac{\tan(x)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(x)}}\\&=\lim_{x \to \pi/2^-}\frac{1+\tan^2(x)}{\frac{\tan(x)(1+\tan^2(x))}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(x)}}}\\&=\lim_{x \to \pi/2^-}\frac{1}{\sin(x)}\end{align} so the limit is $\pm 1$, and (i) and (ii) follow.

My issue with this solution is that is appears to me to be an invalid application of l'Hopital's Rule. Specifically, this particular l'Hpoital's Rule variant was previously proven in Chapter 11 Problem 56, which has the strict requirement in its antecedent that:

> $\lim_{x \to a^-} f'(x)/g'(x)=\ell \in \mathbb R$

Letting $f(x)=\tan(x)$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{1+\tan^2(x)}$, all we know is that $\lim_{x \to \pi/2^-}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\lim_{x \to \pi/2^-}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$. Why is it the case that $\lim_{x \to \pi/2^-}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)} \in \mathbb R$?  i.e. if we don't even know anything about $\sin(x)$'s limit, why should we know anything about $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$'s limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm if Spivak really wrote this, then it is an uncharacteristically poor solution I think. To apply L’Hopital’s rule, we need to know for instance that the numerator and denominator both approach $\infty$. But if we know this, then we can compute the limit by a simple algebraic manipulation (divide the top and bottom by $\tan x$). This gives a limit of $1$, and also proves the existence of the limit.

This solution assumes $\sin x$ has a limit and is non-zero (so that $1/\sin x$ also has a limit) and that $\tan x\to \infty$ as $x\to (\pi/2)^-$ (but like I said, if you already know this (it follows from part (a)) then you’re done).

Comment: I remember doing this problem and thinking it was such a cool way of introducing trigonometry, but not this specific way of doing the limit (I guess I must have borrowed an older edition of Spivak)

Comment: Hmmm. Would you mind clarifying your proposed solution in the first paragraph? It seems like you are saying that $\lim \sin(x)=\lim \frac{\tan(x)}{\sqrt{(1+\tan^2(x)}}=\lim \frac{\frac{\tan(x))}{\tan(x)}}{\frac{\sqrt{(1+\tan^2(x)}}{\tan(x)}}=1$. If so, I am not sure I follow the final equality.

Comment: yes. simplify the algebra. It’s the same trick as showing $\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\to 1$.

Comment: ahhh. Got it. Thank you.

Comment: For anyone needing more specificity: $\lim \frac{\frac{\tan(x))}{\tan(x)}}{\frac{\sqrt{(1+\tan^2(x)}}{\tan(x)}}=\lim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1+\tan^2(x)}{\tan^2(x)}}}=\lim\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\tan^2(x)}+1}}$. Now, from the inverse's domain, we know that $\tan(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to \pi/2^-$, so $\frac{1}{\tan^2(x)} \to0$.